# Huge Data transfer (both fetch and insert 40 Million of records) using java from Greenplum to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a scenario of loading 40 Million to 100 million records in one trigger. So, could you please suggest the best way to fetch the records from Greenplum and to insert into PostgreSQL.

Also, please suggest as the load is more should I increase memory size.

Currently I'm using `batchUpdate()` using JDBCTemplate

```
postgresqlJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertOpportunitiesDataQuery, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override

                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    Opportunities Opportunities = OpportunitiesList.get(i);
                    ps.setString(1, Opportunities.getOpptyId());
                    ps.setString(2, Opportunities.getOpptySalesStage());
                    ps.setDouble(3, Opportunities.getLineAmountUsd());
                    ps.setString(4, Opportunities.getMustWinIndicator());
                    ps.setString(5, Opportunities.getLineType());
                    ps.setInt(6, Opportunities.getExpectedOrderYear());
                    ps.setInt(7, Opportunities.getExpectedOrderQuarter());
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return OpportunitiesList.size();
                }
              });
```

Comment: The Postgres JDBC driver will buffer the whole result in memory unless you configure it differently - maybe the Greenplum JDBC driver does the same. See here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: Performance wise the best option is to use COPY.

Comment: Could you help in code wise which way I can proceed to fetch avg. of 70 Millions records and insert them.

Comment: As no of records are too much to transfer, single CPU, VM or instance will take time.
One solution I suggest is one app will read data and push it to queue and multiple subscribers will read and insert into another db.

This solution will work as expected if you wanted to process in between, COPY is also a good option.

Comment: You could use postgres_fdw (or greenplum_fdw) to connect to greenplum and pull the data across with a regular INSERT statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jeremy. I can able to fetch the data using postgres_fdw. But I'm not able to store the data which I have imported.

Comment: Why can't you store the imported data?

Comment: Now I can able to store using commit; but I have another issue. When I'm reading the data using fdw I cannot able to read as do like for another normal tables. it is saying 'Greenplum Database does not support REPEATABLE READ transactions.' to resolve I have to execute  'START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;' which is not possible for me to execute everytime.